# Why was my question about finding an artist removed?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, asking-questions

i had [a question on a dev site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/101237/sprite-artist-for-hire) removed for looking for another dev? (wanted to hire an artist) just curious why would that be on a site for dev's to congregate? I think this is a great site, the people are great. Why was the question removed?

Comment: The reason the site is great is we have well defined rules about what kind of content we allow here. Where to find artists or asking to hire artists is not on topic. Try here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12846/where-can-i-go-to-find-a-game-graphic-artist and learn more about the site at the [help].

Comment: ok, thank you Byte56. And not to be rude, i am new here. so where can i find this list of rules so i do not break them again.

Comment: The Help button up top: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 2):

The stackexchange network isn't your standard forum where people just post a topic and get replies. This is a question and answer network, where people post questions about problems and other people post answers. It's not an "anything gamedev goes" type of place. The goal is creating a searchable resource to provide solutions to problems that many game developers face.

The type of questions you can ask are pretty well defined in the help, specifically the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page.

You'll notice that job offers or where to find assets are not part of the questions that are on topic. These questions are either advertising or too broad.